# Unable to connect NodeJS app in Azure App Services to Azure MySQL Database

Tags: mysql, node.js, azure, sequelize.js, azure-web-app-service

I have deployed an NodeJS (with ExpressJS, Sequelize) to Azure App Services. The simple APIs with no database connection work, however when I use the part of the app where I load the data from my Azure MySQL Database, it's having problem with certificate. I get this log message from App Service Log Stream:

```
Unhandled rejection SequelizeConnectionError: unable to get local issuer certificate
```

[image]

I have followed the steps from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/mysql/howto-connect-webapp) on how to enable firewall and use the certificate (BaltimoreCyberTrustRoot.crt.pem).

Using the same instruction, from my laptop, I can connect to the remote Azure MySQL database, using this CLI:

```
$ mysql -h <my-db>.mysql.database.azure.com -u <my-user> --ssl-mode=REQUIRED --ssl-ca=.\BaltimoreCyberTrustRoot.crt.pem -p
```

I have followed other StackOverflow / Github questions related to this and I followed their configurations like this:

```
const mysql = require('mysql2');
...
var sequelize = new Sequelize(config.db, config.username, config.password, {
    host:    "<my-db>.mysql.database.azure.com",
    port:    3306,
    dialect: 'mysql',
    dialectOptions: {
        ssl: {
            ca: fs.readFileSync(__dirname + "/ssl/BaltimoreCyberTrustRoot.crt.pem")
        }
    }
});
```

Do I need to set additional key/cert under `ssl`?

```
ssl: {
    key: fs.readFileSync(__dirname + "./certs/client-key.pem"),
    cert: fs.readFileSync(__dirname + "./certs/client-cert.pem"),
    ca: fs.readFileSync(__dirname + "/ssl/BaltimoreCyberTrustRoot.crt.pem")
}
```

I am using Node 12 (Node 12.13 in Azure App Service) and here's my `package.json` dependencies:

```
"dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "faker": "^4.1.0",
    "mysql2": "^2.1.0",
    "sequelize": "^5.21.5"
}
```

Comment: @Jason Thanks for the answer. I haven't gone back to it as I work on it during weekends only. But I will accept your answer once I tested it, cheer!.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According my test, I can connect to mysql. You can add additional key/cert yes or not.

If you add, you can see my code like below,

```
/*configuration*/
const sequelizeInstance  = new Sequelize("***db", "azure_root@***mysql", "Ja***.****20", {
host: "***mysql.mysql.database.azure.com",
dialect: 'mysql',
dialectOptions: {
    ssl: {
        ca: fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname, 'BaltimoreCyberTrustRoot.crt.pem'));
    }
}
});

/*test connection*/
try
{
    sequelizeInstance.authenticate();
    console.log('Connection has been established successfully.');
} 
catch (error) {
    console.error('Unable to connect to the database:', error);
}
```

If not, you just set `ssl=true` like the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/azure/mysql/concepts-ssl-connection-security) .

Hope it's useful to u.